# Don't apply changes to laravel project

Tags: css, image, laravel

I have a problem with a project in Laravel, the problem is that when you edit CSS code or add images and reload the page, changes do not apply.

eg I had an image called 1.jpg which was then deleted, replaced with 2.jpg. I edited the code calling the image 2.jpg, but even after reloading the page, 2.jpg is not displayed.

It is not browser cache - I've tried clearing it, but the issue remains. This also happens to me when I edit CSS - the changes are not applied. Any ideas? I've used Sublime text 2 and 3 with windows 8.1.

I've tried `php artisan cache: clear`, deleting the cache of the project, and no luck. I'm going crazy, can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: Does removing the files in `app/storage/views` do the trick? I've had to do that a number of times.

Comment: from the command line, does 'php artisan env' return 'local'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the css in the `resources/sass/app.scss` then you need to run after it `npm run dev` , this will compile your css.

I suggest adding the css internally in the file in the head tags or even inline css. But everytime you make changes to your `resources/sass/app.scss` you need to run `npm run dev`